# using jquery extend to avoid editing jquery standard libraries

Tags: jquery, ajax, extend

I want add some functionality to the jquery $.ajax call.  Specifically I want to trap for http error 403.  I prefer not to edit jquery JS itself.  I started to look at .extend but am a little confused by the examples.

Can I $.extend $.ajax() with to trap for 403?

TIA
Zombie Killer.

Answer (score 2):

Have you looked at [jQuery.ajaxSetup](http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax/jQuery.ajaxSetup#options) options?  Or at [jQuery.ajaxError](http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax/ajaxError#callback)?

Either way, don't edit the jQuery source.

Answer (score 0):

Extend doesn't work like that. You might  be better served by something like this:

```
jQuery.fn.myCustomAjax = function() {
    // custom code here
    jQuery.ajax(); // etc
};
```

The #1 major benefit of this is that it won't stuff with any external code (plugins) and will be much easier to work with when you upgrade jQuery.

Comment: This is a decent and low-risk solution if you write/control the code that invokes $.ajax().  If, on the other hand, you're trying to detect 403 in 3rd-party JS code -- such as jQuery plugins -- you need something else.

Comment: @Drew - it's simple enough to save it first with something like: **$._origAjax=$.ajax;** then override the **$.ajax** function, but it's not a trivial fix in any event.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Guys.  The suggested solution wont work becuase I need to trap for specific http result codes and then "do something special" via javascript.

so I have added 5 lines of code to jquery core library (I know dont flame me).  To solve this problem in the core I suggest the following parameter would be added to jquery core libs (new parameter is responseHandlers)

```
$.ajax(
     responseHandlers: {
          "403":function() { http403(); } ,
          "500":function() { http500(); }
     }
```

global scoped:

```
function http403()
{
}

function http500()
{
}
```